# Кто шарит в Астрономии помогите

Tags: физика

В повести Г. Голубева «Улугбек» есть следующая фраза: «...Марс и Венера
движутся в одну сторону – с запада на восток, потом они останавливаются и вдруг
направляются обратно на запад и так несколько раз за ночь
движутся в одну сторону — с запада на восток, потом останавливаются и
вдруг направляются обратно на запад, и так несколько раз за ночь...»
Укажите ошибку в приведенном отрывке.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что не по теме сайта

Comment: Видимо описано попятное движения, но оно не может случаться дважды за ночь

Comment: @astromen вам с таким вопросом вот сюда: https://physics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Иван-Ипатов там на русском ответят?

Comment: Ну ко всему Венера не может быть видной всю ночь. Она видна либо вечером, либо утром.

Comment: @astromen, нет, там по-английски

Answer (score 1):

описанное явление называется ["попятным движением"](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8B#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8F%CC%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20(%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5)%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B6%D0%B5%CC%81%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%CC%81%D1%82%20%E2%80%94,%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B0%20(%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%83)%20%D0%B8%20%D0%9B%D1%83%D0%BD%D1%8B), наблюдаться оно НЕ МОЖЕТ по нескольку раз за сутки, скорее наоборот, может наблюдаться несколько раз в год

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]